# Invoke-Command seemingly converting my commas to spaces

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script which remotely starts a program with given command line arguments. For some reason, the commas in one of my strings (in format --Tags Small,Medium,Large) is getting changes to spaces sometime between Invoke-Command and when the application reads the args.

Powershell:

```
param(
[string]$N = "remoteHost",
[string]$U = "user",
[string]$P = "pass",
[string]$App = "App.exe",
[string]$Arg = "--Tags Small,Medium,Large"
)
Write-Host "Connecting to" $N "..."
$sec = ConvertTo-secureString $P -asPlainText -Force
$session=New-PSSession -ComputerName $N -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($U,$sec))
$cmd = $App + " " + $Arg
Write-Host $cmd
$sb = ([scriptblock]::Create($cmd))
Write-Host $cmd
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $sb
Write-Host "Disconnecting..."
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

Both $cmd and $sb Write-Host's show what I expect:

```
"App.exe --Tags Small,Medium,Large"
```

But in the "App.exe" application, it is receiving args:

```
"--Tags Small Medium Large"
```

If I run App.exe via commandline with the exact same string, it sees the commas as expected so I think the conversion is happening in the powershell.

The only thing in between the app and the last Write-Host is the Invoke-Command, so I am thinking somehow it is converting the commas to spaces. My question is:

1. Why is the comma converted?
2. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert a command string

```
"App.exe --Tags Small,Medium,Large"
```

to a scriptblock. The result is the same as if you'd created the scriptblock like this:

```
$sb = {App.exe --Tags Small,Medium,Large}
```

When you invoke that scriptblock the parser interprets `Small,Medium,Large` as a string array. However, because you're running an external command your commandline is converted to a string somewhere along the way (because at the end of the day that's what [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) expects). Mangling a string array into a string concatenates the array elements with the [output field separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#ofs) (`$OFS`, by default a space), so the array becomes `Small Medium Large` and your commandline ends up being

```
App.exe --Tags Small Medium Large
```

To avoid this behavior put the argument in quotes, so that it's passed as one comma-separated string:

```
[string]$Arg = "--Tags 'Small,Medium,Large'"
```

Comment: So when I was calling Write-Host $sb, the commas I saw were not actually there, thats just how powershell formats scriptblocks? Frustrating coincidence. I tested the fix and it worked

Comment: The commas were there. But they get removed when you invoke the scriptblock and the command is actually parsed. You should see the same behavior if you simply enter `App.exe --Tags Small,Medium,Large` in a PowerShell console.

Answer (score 0):

The powershell parser is interpreting the "Small,Medium,Large" as an array and expanding them as 3 separate arguments. You will have to do some quoting to convince powershell to interpret them as a single string and pass them on as a single argument:

```
$Arg = "--Tags '""Small,Medium,Large""'"
```